# Run controller tests with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to run a rake test using devise (using a user that's been created by database seeds)

Running `rake test` produces the following error:

```
Failure:
CustomersControllerTest#test_should_get_index [/home/ubuntu/workspace/test/controllers/customers_controller_test.rb:7]:
Expected response to be a <2XX: success>, but was a <302: Found> redirect to <http://www.example.com/users/sign_in>
Response body: <html><body>You are being <a href="http://www.example.com/users/sign_in">redirected</a>.</body></html>
```

My test looks like this:

```
test "should get index" do
    get customers_url
    assert_response :success
end
```

It's a very simple test, but I don't know how to actually login to the site before performing the test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To test actions that require an authenticated user you can use Devise's `sign_in` and `sign_out` helpers. These come from `Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers` on your test case or its parent class (or `Devise::Test::IntegrationHelpers` for Rails 5+):

```
class CustomersControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers # <-- Include helpers
  test "should get index" do
    sign_in User.create(...) # <-- Create and authenticate a user
    get customers_url
    assert_response :success
  end
end
```

See the [controller tests](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#controller-tests) section in the Devise README for details.

Comment: For all of you who don't follow the link and despair: For Rails >= 5 you need to ```include Devise::Test::IntegrationHelpers```. Also note that it is possible to use fixtures (e.g. ```sign_in admins(:one)```